# How to store ExtensionDataObject in List in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I want to bind html drop down List using Services. The service the return type is `ExtensionDataObject` How can i get data from this or how to store this values into list? Is it possible or not if not any other approach please help me
I want to store these data into List and i will call you from ASPX using j Query

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static List<CountryList> GetCountriesName(string UserID)
        {
            GetInitiatorList.MasterDataServiceClient oClient = new GetInitiatorList.MasterDataServiceClient();
            string userid = "approver01";
            string work = "4";
            oClient.GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow(userid, work);// Return type is ExtensionDataObject
            List<string> lst = new List<string>();
            {
         lst.Add(oClient.GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow(userid, work).ToString());
            return lst;//Error on this line 
            }
        }
        public class CountryList
        {
            private ExtensionDataObject extensionDataObject_value;
            public ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
            {
                get
                {
                    return extensionDataObject_value;
                }
                set
                {
                    extensionDataObject_value = value;
                }
            }
            [DataMember]
            public string Name;
        }
```

I want to retrieve company name for Binding Company drop down list but i unable Intelligence is showing but don't how to use them

Click on image and Zoom this pic to see Clear.

[image]

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @stuartd Can not convert from myProjectName.GetIntiatorList.INITIATORLIST to myProjectName.Header.CountryList

Comment: Use linq Select method to convert from InitiatorList to CountryList type

Comment: @AmitShahani can you just give me sample code for that ?